# Geting empty array when find with some criteria in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
var Config = require('../Config');

var serviceAvailability = new Schema({
    agentId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'agentProfile', required: true},
    availabilityDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    availabilityTime: {type: Array, required: true} 
});

serviceAvailability.index({agentId:1 , availabilityDate:1},{unique:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('serviceAvailability', serviceAvailability);
```

Controller :

```
Models.serviceAvailability.find({'agentId':'abcd'}, function (err, service) {
    console.log(service);
    if(service) {
        callback(err , service);
    }
    else {
        callback(err);
    }
});
```

I am trying to get all data with some criteria like if agentId is equal to some value but whenever i am using any criteria to find data i am getting empty array while if i remove the criteria and find all data then i am getting data, why is this ?

Comment: Have you checked if `Models.agentProfile.findById('abcd')` yields a result?

Comment: Well "abcd" is not an `ObjectId`. You need to put in a valid `ObjectId` value or at least string that equals the hex value returned. Or you seem to be trying to match a "field" within the "agentProfile" objects, and the latter is just not possible. Not without populating and manually filtering.

Comment: abcd is just to tell you as a example, in real i am sending proper ObjectId,
and yes i tried all same query in mongo terminal and then working fine from mongo terminal @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

I think, you try to find a mongoDB document with a request on ObjectId Field, but, in your example, you don't use a correct ObjectId String Value.

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

So, this is a correct way to request your serviceAbility with a correct ObjectId :

```
Models.serviceAvailability.find({
    'agentId':'507f1f77bcf86cd799439011'
}, function (err, service) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
        return;
    }
    callback(null, service);
});
```

In this case, you should have an `agentProfile` with the `_id` equals to `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`

Comment: I assumed that `abcd` in the question was just a placeholder :-)

Comment: abcd is just to tell you as a example, in real i am sending proper ObjectId